# Bind a switch state to a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning swift by building a basic counting app (based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3blma4PCRak) and I'm trying to have a function that counts on increments of 3 based on the state of a switch.

It seems a lot of the answers I find in tutorials online and from SO are from many years ago and a lot of the syntax is deprecated, including:

• instead of `oddSwitch.On` now it is `oddSwitch.isOn`

• Stating colors changed from `UIColor.redColor` to just `UIColor.red`

And so on...below is my code thus far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestApp
//
//  Created by kawnah on 2/8/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 kawnah. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var outputLabel: UILabel? = UILabel();

    var currentCount = 0;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addOneBUtton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        currentCount = currentCount + 1

        if currentCount <= 1 {
            outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) click"
        } else {
            outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) clicks"
        }

        outputLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red

    }


    @IBOutlet var oddSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func oddToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if oddSwitch!.isOn {
            currentCount = currentCount + 3
        }
    }

}
```

I'm confused as to the relationship between the `@IBOutlet` and my function that states to count in increments of three. I've tried including weak storage as well but it's to my understanding that is the default for `@IBOutlet`. Currently when I toggle the switch on, the counter still increments by 1.

My error log simply shows compression errors for PNGs for my splash screen, nothing with the code. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your addOneBUtton code to match this.

```
@IBAction func addOneBUtton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if oddSwitch!.isOn {
        currentCount = currentCount + 3
    } else {
        currentCount = currentCount + 1
    }
    if currentCount <= 1 {
        outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) click"
    } else {
        outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) clicks"
    }

    outputLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red

}
```

And you can remove this section.

```
@IBAction func oddToggle(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if oddSwitch!.isOn {
        currentCount = currentCount + 3
    }
}
```

So the complete code should look something like this.

```
import UIKit

class testViewController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var outputLabel: UILabel? = UILabel();
    @IBOutlet var oddSwitch: UISwitch!

    //MARK: Vars
    var currentCount = 0;

    //MARK: Lifecyle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //MARK: IBActions
    @IBAction func addOneBUtton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if oddSwitch!.isOn {
            currentCount = currentCount + 3
        } else {
            currentCount = currentCount + 1
        }
        if currentCount <= 1 {
            outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) click"
        } else {
            outputLabel?.text = "\(currentCount) clicks"
        }

        outputLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red

    }

}
```

Note: This was my twist on keeping the code clean with `IBOutlets` all in one spots and using `//MARK:` to the sections of code quicker to jump to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm brand new and need to read more but running your solution throws `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` Why would the switch throw nil? The name of the switch is `oddSwitch`

Comment: You need to reconnect the `@IBOutlet var oddSwitch: UISwitch!` back to the storyboard and that will fix that issue.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Interesting!